# Continuous function - $|\int_C f(z)dz| \leq 4$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

**Question :** Let the continuous function $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(z)| \leq 1$ and $C$ be the unit circle in the positive direction. Show that $\left|\int_C f(z)dz\,\right| \leq 4$.

**Solution :** Let $$I = \left|\int_C f(z)dz\,\right|$$ and $$\int_C f(z)dz = \left|\int_C f(z)dz\,\right| e^{i \gamma}.$$ Then $$I =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(e^{it})ie^{i(t-\gamma)}dt \stackrel{(*)}= \Re\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(e^{it})ie^{i(t-\gamma)}dt\right) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} -f(e^{it})\sin(t-\gamma)dt \leq$$ $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left|\sin(t-\gamma)\,\right|dt = 4$$

Is anyone could explain to me the equality (*)?

Answer (score 3):

If we have
$$
I = \left|\int_C f(z)dz\right|
$$ it means that the complex number $I$ is a **real number** thus identity $(*)$ tells that $I$ is equal to its **real part**.